how to capture login method in a djangp project and show it on user profile that he has logged in using google, Facebook or email and password
how to capture login method in a djangp project and show it on user profile that he has logged in using google, facebook or email and password,
I have written this logic to capture the login method:
@login_required  # Use with caution! Consider alternative security measures
def login_method_view(request):
    print("hiiiii")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            print("inside try block")
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            login_method = data.get('login_method', '')
            if login_method in ['facebook', 'google', 'email']:
                user = request.user  # Corrected typo
                if user.is_authenticated():
                    print("user is auth.")
                    profile = user.profile
                    if login_method == 'facebook':
                        print("the login method is facebook")
                        profile.logged_in_via_facebook = True
                        profile.logged_in_via_google = False
                        profile.logged_in_via_email = False
                        print(profile.log_in_via_facebook)
                    elif login_method == 'google':
                        print("the login method is google")
                        profile.logged_in_via_google = True
                        profile.logged_in_via_facebook = False
                        profile.logged_in_via_email = False
                        print(profile.log_in_via_google)
                    elif login_method == 'email':
                        print("the login method is email")
                        profile.logged_in_via_email = True
                        profile.logged_in_via_google = False
                        profile.logged_in_via_facebook = False
                        print(profile.log_in_via_email)
                    profile.save()
                    print("hello, how r u")
                    return JsonResponse({"status": "success", "message": "user logged in via " + login_method})
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({"status": "error", "message": "user is not authenticated."}, status=401)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({"status": "error", "message": str(e)}, status=400)
    return HttpResponse(status=405)  # Method Not Allowed if not GET reque

but I am not able to trigger this function it's in vews.py file and in urls.py I have written this url:
url(r'^login-method-view/$', views.login_method_view, name = 'login_method_view')

but whenever I am running my server my function is not triggering.
I want to captuer the login method so that i can show those methods on users profile.
